# Capture the users clicks inside our SharePoint modern home page (how click on quick link modern news, etc..)

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, microsoft-graph, graph-api, logs

We have a SharePoint online modern page which contains, those main Web Parts:-

1. Quick links
2. News web part

now we want to capture the users clicks and store them inside a SharePoint online list to show the statistics inside Power Apps or Power BI. so if UserA clicks on quick link named "Our Website" >> to capture this info inside a SharePoint custom list:-

Title---> CreatedBy

Our Website---> UserA

Our Website---> UserB

so how we can build such a feature? and can we benefit from the Graph API to get those info and show them inside Power Apps or Power BI instead of building this from scratch ?

Comment: SharePoint audit logs?

Comment: @Christoffer but how we can build a sharepoint list with those results? also i am using sharepoint online

Comment: how about creating spfx and embed that in that page. That SPFX will not have any UI and on load it will save the user info in the list, before saving in the list check if user already exists for that date.

Comment: @Saira and how i can capture which link/s the users click on  inside the SPFX?

Comment: You can capture that link with a link event in SPFX. I will try to create an example for you

Comment: @Saira yes please that will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding SPFX in that page. As an example I have called a function and capturing the quick links. Please note that I am using Quiklinks of compact layout option.
[image]

In SPFX , call the custom function and in that function capture the a href of the quick links

```
  private TestFunction(): void {
    $(document).off().on('click', 'div[class=ms-List-cell]', function() {
        var qLink = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        console.log(`qLink `); 
        console.log(qLink); Here check qLinks if that is of your company then add in SharePoint with current user.
  });
```

}

Hope this will give you some direction

Comment: thanks for the code and info,, but in SharePoint in general and SharePoint online specifically those markups can be changed, am i correct?

Comment: I have tested in different browsers, as long as you are referring the class names which are generic , you are good to go

Comment: the markup does not have to do with the browser version, i mean Microsoft can change those markups..

Comment: Yes it may… there is no other way to capture what you want . One way is you May update your SPFX and save the class names in separate class so you can update in one place only. And I don’t think Microsoft will do frequent updates to their class

Comment: ok so you mean after capturing the markup, i need to send a RESt api call to create a new entry inside the sharepoint list?

Comment: Yes, Once you captured the markup and you have added the logic to capture what link you want to work on , then you can can use Rest Api or use Pnp to save in the desired SP List and using spfx you already would be having the user who is doing the click. In your logic do check if entry is already there within ( say half hr ) time space then dont add.

Comment: Please mark it as answered if it has given you the direction to your question.